# Only use 2G for calls?

Tags: mobile-network, android-10, 4g, 2g, realme

My current phone unfortunately does not support VoLTE, so I'm limited to 2G for calls.

However, for all other uses (internet, messaging), even the worst LTE reception is still infinitely better than 2G. In areas with low LTE coverage, my phone switches down to 2G, despite me not intending to make a call.

When I then wish to go online, I have to manually open up the secret menu, force it to use the weak LTE signal (by setting it to "LTE ONLY"), and remember to turn it back to its automatic mode when I want to make or receive a call.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Only ever connect to useless 2G when making calls, and forcing LTE in *all* other situations?

The "preferred network type" option in the settings ("LTE/3G/2G (Auto)", "3G/2G (Auto)", "2G Only") also seems to be very backwards for modern usage.

Comment: When on LTE without VoLTE support, doesn't the phone switch back to 3G on phone calls anyway? AFAIR that's the specification. Just not sure if your "enforce" can/does override that.

Comment: If it's on LTE on its own, it does. When I set it to "LTE only" in the "phone info" screen - which is neccessary to prevent it from going to 2G under low reception - it stays on LTE and can't connect calls.

Comment: Ah! That fact – LTE **only** – was not clear. Let's integrate that with your question, shall we? // Good luck, I hope someone does have a solution for this (I unfortunately don't)…